# Determine Cargo build configuration

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

I'm implementing a [custom Cargo subcommand](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/external-tools.html#custom-subcommands) that mostly runs `cargo build` followed by some processing on a successful invocation. Cargo itself supports several ways to customize defaults, (e.g. the `--target` selected when omitted), which this subcommand exposes as well.

The challenge now is to find the defaults that `cargo build` uses from the subcommand implementation. With build scripts getting access to [all sorts of information](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/environment-variables.html#environment-variables-cargo-sets-for-build-scripts), this isn't the case for [subcommands](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/environment-variables.html#environment-variables-cargo-sets-for-3rd-party-subcommands). Running [cargo metadata](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/commands/cargo-metadata.html) doesn't seem to produce that information either (such as the `TARGET`).

Is there any way to query Cargo about the configuration it will be using for a `cargo build` invocation, and make that available to a Cargo custom subcommand?

Comment: https://github.com/rust-lang/cargo/wiki/Third-party-cargo-subcommands contains a list of other cargo subcommand maybe that could help you. But I don't fully understand why you want this, call `cargo build` will do the job alone.

Comment: @sta It sure will. But then my subcommand will want to do some more processing. For that to work it will need to know where Cargo just built artifacts into.